# В symfony2 crud generator не выводит поля которые ссылаются на другие таблицы (reference foreighn key)

Tags: postgresql, symfony2, crud

Я использую базу PostgreSQL. Команда для генерации CRUD:

```
php app/console doctrine:generate:crud --entity=AdminBundle:Categories --route-prefix=admin/categories --with-write --format=annotation --no-interaction --overwrite
```

Структура таблицы:

```
create table CATEGORIES(
    id SERIAL primary key
    , parent int not null references PARENT_CATEGORIES (id) on delete cascade
    , uri varchar(60) not null unique CONSTRAINT TSCO_CATEGORIES_CH_URI check ( uri not like '% %' )
    , name varchar(60) not null -- Название категории
    , ...
);
```

В вьюшке `index` поля `id`, `uri`, `name` выводятся, а вот поле parent не выводится. Оно появляется только в `edit`. Но если вручную добавить, то без проблем указывает на название PROJECT, на который оно и ссылается. Как мне заставить CRUD по-умолчанию показывать такие поля?

Comment: Буду благодарен, если кто ни будь этот вопрос переведет и выложит на английскую часть! ))

Comment: отвечайте здесь http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30434614/symfony-crud-generated-index-view-where-is-not-have-references-fields полагается премия

Comment: Я думаю, что Вам следует закрыть этот вопрос или же самому на него ответить, исходя из ответов, полученных на оригинальном SO.